# Make UIButton within sub view accessible to parent viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a subview within my applications views as set up by this user guide:

http://patientprogrammer.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/re-usable-subviews-in-ios/

I have a UIView which is the file owner of the sub views .xib file which displays the view with:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib

{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"headerview" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view_header];
}
```

Now this subview has a button within it that I need to be clickable. Is it possible to access this button from the parent views UIViewController?

Comment: Why not have a delegate communicate the button click event up the chain?

Comment: sure, I am just looking for a workable solution to passing on the click event, if you have a solution that would be great

Answer (score 1):

1. First define the protocol in your subview headerView (headerView.h) as:

   ```
   @protocol headerViewDelegate;

   @interface hearderView : UIView 
   @property (nonatomic,strong)IBAction UIButton * button1;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) id<headerViewDelegate> delegate;

   @end

   @protocol headerViewDelegate <NSObject>

   @optional

   -(void)didClickedButton1;

   @end
   ```
2. In the button clicked method in .m file

   ```
   [self.delegate didClickedButton1];
   ```

   (This says the delegate of this view will execute this didClickedButton1: method )
   (Viewcontroller can become delegate if it conforms to this  protocol in their header file)
3. Now, in the parent view controller:

   a. conform to use headerViewDelegate
    import “headerview”
    put

   b. now you can put the method didClickedButton1 in the parent view controller.
    this is called when you click the button1.

   ```
    -(void) didClickedButton1{

     //do your stuffs here
     }
   ```

   This method is called in the parent view controller when you click the button in the subview because in the parent view controller we are saying i'm the delegate of you ( subview ) and i 'm gonna do the task what you have mentioned in your protocol ( here is -(void) didClickedButton1: method ).